# Passing data to another component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new in Angular I want to pass data from one to another component. I store that in array that is isn't bind with component.html i wonder that i use @Input property if is isn't bind or some other manner?

Comment: you need to look at this document https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: do bit research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding  a inject a service for both component then put the data in the service so both can find it. Also you can use the @input and the @output directive , but i prefer the service ( In this service both share the varible is ready ) :

```
import {EventEmitter, Injectable} from '@angular/core';

      @Injectable()
      export class LoadPageService {
          private isReady= false;
          // Event emitter that make event each time the variabe isReady 
           changes
         Updated: EventEmitter <boolean>= new EventEmitter();
        setdata( value) {
          this.isReady = value;
            this.Updated.emit(this.isReady);
        }

          getdata() {
          return this.isReady;
        }

      }
```